# user defined goClicked funtion is not executing.Suggest me a solution

Tags: java, android

"goClicked" function is a onClick function to the button "Go" but it is not executing when I click on the button "Go"( I am able to say this because the toast is not appearing ) until I comment the while loop in "goClicked" function. I am pasting the code for only 2 functions "goClicked" and "countdown" because they are the only functions that alter the variable "counterRunning".

```
    public void goClicked(View view) {
    afterGoPressed();
    countDown();
    correctCount = 0;
    totalCount = 0;
    TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    while (counterRunning) {
        int sum = generateQuestion();
        pickOption = generateOptions(sum);

    }

}
 public void countDown() {
            counterRunning = true;
            final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
            final Button tryAgain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tryAgain);
            final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
            final TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            int secondsLeft = 30;

            time.setText(secondsLeft+"");
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    time.setText(millisUntilFinished/1000 + "");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    tryAgain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    result.setText("Your score: " + score.getText());
                    result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    counterRunning = false;
                }
            }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're using an infinite loop with the following code:

```
while (counterRunning) {
    int sum = generateQuestion();
    pickOption = generateOptions(sum);

}
```

the code will blocking all other instruction until it found the `counterRunning` is changed to `false` **inside the while block**. But it never happened. Hence the infinite loop.

Comment: so how should overcome this?